# Array.Sort works... Sometimes

Tags: c#, sorting

I'm developing a game in vanilla C#, however, I got in a problem when I try to sort the objects I'm trying to render.

The graphics engine renders objects based on its Z and Y position. So before I render the objects, I try to sort them.

However, when the objects render, they show like this:

[image: nope]

(Those are 4 isometric blocks, all at the same Y, the two on the front have 8 Z, and the ones in the back 0 Z)

When they should show like this, since they're all at the same Y, but different Z:

[image: yes]

It's also worth mentioning that they don't always show like in picture 1, but rather sometimes like that, in other frames oe block behind and other in front, etc.

Here's the code used for rendering:

```
        private void render()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            RenderObject[] todrawnow = todraw.ToArray();
            Array.Sort(todrawnow);
            foreach (RenderObject img in todrawnow)
            {
                if (img!=null)
                    drawHandle.DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped(img.img, new Rectangle(img.x, img.y+img.z, 32, 48));
            }
        }
    }
```

And the RenderObject class:

```
    public class RenderObject : IComparable<RenderObject>
{
    public Image img;
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int z;

    public RenderObject(Image img, int x, int y, int z)
    {
        this.img = img;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public int CompareTo(RenderObject other)
    {
        // Z sort if y is equal. [High to low]
        if (y == other.y)
        {
            return z.CompareTo(other.z);
        }
        // Default to y sort. [High to low]
        return other.y.CompareTo(y);
    }
}
```

P.S: Y is altitude, and Z is the front axis, they're not the same.

Comment: It's not necessary to call **CompareTo** on an **int**, just use < > == etc

Comment: What do you expect from `z.CompareTo(other.z);` line? Forgot `return`? :)

Comment: Oops!! Fixing that right now!

Comment: @IvanStoev Still does the same thing...

Comment: Please use a simple `for` instead of `foreach` ;).

Comment: Done, still same problem

Comment: Pictures look tiny, it's not clear what you are trying to illustrate with them.

Comment: What about `var todrawnow = todraw.OrderBy(o=> o.y).ThenBy(o=> o.z).ToArray();` ;).

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `CompareTo` ignores the result of Z comparison when `y`s are the same:

```
public int CompareTo(RenderObject other)
{
    // Z sort if y is equal. [High to low]
    if (y == other.y)
    {
        z.CompareTo(other.z); // <<== This line has no effect on sorting
    }
    // Default to y sort. [High to low]
    return other.y.CompareTo(y);
}
```

You should add `return` in front of `z`-order comparison:

```
if (y == other.y)
{
    return z.CompareTo(other.z);
}
```

You could further simplify this code by running `y` comparison first:

```
public int CompareTo(RenderObject other)
{
    int res = other.y.CompareTo(y);
    return res != 0 ? res : z.CompareTo(other.z);
}
```

Comment: @AlexINF Put a breakpoint at `foreach` in the debugger, and check the content of `todrawnow`. It should be in the proper order as specified by your code, i.e. ordered by `Y`, with ties broken by `Z`.

Comment: The order seems fine when I breakpoint it... It doesn't even change.

Comment: @AlexINF You order by `Y` and then by `Z`, but your rectangle is placed at `Y+Z` on rendering. Shouldn't you be sorting on `Y+Z` instead?

Comment: No, since Y has more priority than Z. Y is altitude, so if a block has Y 8 it should be rendering above other blocks, when Z is the front axis, so if a block has Z 8 it should be only in front of the block behind it.

Comment: Apart from that, it would result in the same output, since the blocks in the picture all have Y 0, so Y doesn't have anything to do with this.

Comment: @AlexINF Also your comment says "High to low" in both cases, but `Z` order will be "low to high", because you compare "this" `z` to `other.z`.